# IBMQfactory._initialize_providers Error

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

After a successful first run without problems, I found that I cannot connect any longer.

Code:

```
from qiskit import IBMQ
IBMQ.load_account() #previously enabled and saved, even updated
IBMQ.providers()  # returns empty why???
provider = IBMQ.get_provider()
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_16_melbourne')
```

I re-added the token, overwrite the saved token and could successfully activate my account, but it seems that no provider can be found now. 
I get this error

```
ibmqfactory.load_account:WARNING:2020-05-25 22:08:25,390: Credentials are already in use. The existing account in the session will be replaced.
```

```
ibmqfactory._initialize_providers:WARNING:2020-05-25 22:08:29,324: Unable to instantiate provider for {'hub': 'ibm-q', 'group': 'open', 'project': 'main'}: "{'online_date': ['Not a valid datetime.']}"
```

```
ibmqfactory.load_account:WARNING:2020-05-25 22:08:29,325: No Hub/Group/Projects could be found for this account.
```

Even if I directly add the same hub, group and project, I am not able to retrieve a single provider. 
If I run `IBMQ_provider()` I get an empty list.

It is summarized as `IBMQProviderError: 'No provider matches the specified criteria`

If you could give me a had, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Can you see providers if you go on the IBM Quantum Expereince?

Comment: Indeed, if I go to the web-dashboard I can see my past jobs.

Comment: I tried to access thru a web-IDE and it worked without problems. 
Someone knows where can I find the settings or the file in the package?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible your credentials file has got messed up in someway. The best thing to do would be to run `IBMQ.delete_account()` to remove the current account details, regenerate the API token in the IBM Quantum Experience and then save this new token with `IBMQ.save_account(token=new_token, overwrite=True)`

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to a mismatch of `qiskit-terra` and `qiskit-ibmq-provider` versions. If you're using `qiskit-ibmq-provider` 0.7 it requires `qiskit-terra` 0.14. There's a bug in `qiskit-ibmq-provider`'s setup.py that missed this dependency.