# Unable to instantiate provider for research account locally

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

When I run `IBMQ.load_account()`. I have the error information:

```
C:\application\python\anaconda\lib\site-packages\qiskit\providers\ibmq\ibmqfactory.py:192: UserWarning: Timestamps in IBMQ backend properties, jobs, and job results are all now in local time instead of UTC.
```

```
warnings.warn('Timestamps in IBMQ backend properties, jobs, and job results '
ibmqfactory._initialize_providers:WARNING:2020-09-21 15:33:39,682: Unable to instantiate provider for {'hub': 'ibm-q-research', 'group': 'Cheng-Guo', 'project': 'main'}: string indices must be integers.
```

I want to ask about the second warning: Unable to instantiate provider for {'hub': 'ibm-q-research', 'group': 'Cheng-Guo', 'project': 'main'}: string indices must be integers.

My account have two provider:
(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')
{hub: 'ibm-q-research', group: 'Cheng-Guo', project: 'main'}

I can only use the first provider locally. Because of these two questions: "https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12183/ibmqfactory-initialize-providers-error" and "https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13350/qiskit-ibmq-load-account-fails-on-version-0-20-0".

I have tried to `delete` my account then `save` it. But it didn't work.
I have tried to use qiskit 0.21.0, the newest version in Github. But it didn't work.
I have tried to use qiskit 0.20.1, the version in Quantum Lab(https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/jupyter). But it didn't work.

The same version of qiskit (0.20.1) cannot be used locally but `can` be used in the quantum lab, so I can only use the quantum lab to program now. But quantum lab requires a network connection, which is not very convenient.

I have tried to change a PC and install qiskit(version 0.21.0 in default), it didn't work.

I have read the source code and I still can't understand why only the research provider doesn't work, and only don't work locally.

Thank you very much if you can help me.

Comment: What qiskit version do you get when you run `qiskit.__qiskit_version__` after importing qiskit? Also, for the account token, I would try running `IBMQ.delete_account()` and then `IBMQ.save_account(<token>, overwrite=True)`.

Comment: As I said in the description, I have tried two versions of qiskit (0.20.1 and 0.21.0), and also tried to delete the account. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry about that. When you do load your account, what do you get when you run `IBMQ.providers()`?

Comment: When you run `qiskit.__qiskit_version_` it will print out the versions for all of the qiskit elements (terra, ignis, aqua, aer, ibmq-provider). We should confirm that all of the qiskit versions are up to date, because this issue could be caused by a mismatch of versions involving the ibmq-provider.

Comment: @Winona. Thanks for care. I only have `[<AccountProvider for IBMQ(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')>]` when  I run `IBMQ.providers()`

Comment: @Matthew Stypulkoski. Specifically, I have tried these two versions: `{'qiskit-terra': '0.15.2',
 'qiskit-aer': '0.6.1',
 'qiskit-ignis': '0.4.0',
 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.9.0',
 'qiskit-aqua': '0.7.5',
 'qiskit': '0.21.0'}` and `{'qiskit-terra': '0.15.2',
 'qiskit-aer': '0.6.1',
 'qiskit-ignis': '0.4.0',
 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.8.0',
 'qiskit-aqua': '0.7.5',
 'qiskit': '0.20.1'}` .The first one is the same as the one on Github and the second one is the same as the one on Quantum Lab.

Answer (score 0):

Please contact your hub Group Admin to confirm that the email address of the IBM Quantum Experience account you are using has access to this Group.

Comment: I see your email, thank you very much!